# How to use Unity in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: unity, ubuntu-mate

I'm running Ubuntu Mate, and I've installed Unity using sudo apt-get install unity. How can I select Unity as the default interface in Mate?

Comment: You may try to install ubuntu-desktop meta-package with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. And then select Unity session on Login Screen.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, that did the job.